# In python pyramid web framework, how can I drop all db table rows before seeding?

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, sqlalchemy, pyramid, alembic

I am using a cookiecutter to make a pyramid web app.
It has a function to seed the db here:
https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid-cookiecutter-starter/blob/latest/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.repo_name%7D%7D/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.repo_name%7D%7D/sqlalchemy_scripts/initialize_db.py#L15

But if I run it twice, or change the entries that I am adding, I get duplicate entries and errors. I am using a sqlite db with sqlalchemy.

What code can I add inside [setup_models](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid-cookiecutter-starter/blob/latest/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.repo_name%7D%7D/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.repo_name%7D%7D/sqlalchemy_scripts/initialize_db.py#L10) that will drop db all db rows before writing the new model instances?
It would be great if this looped over all models and deleted all instances of them.

```
def setup_models(dbsession):
    """
    Add or update models / fixtures in the database.
    """
    model = models.mymodel.MyModel(name='one', value=1)
    dbsession.add(model)
```

I am updating the db by running:

```
# to run the initial migration that adds the tables to the db, run this once
venv/bin/alembic -c development.ini upgrade head
# seed the data, I want to be able to keep editing the seed data
# and re-run this command and have it will wipe the db rows and insert the seed data defined in setup_models
venv/bin/initialize_suppah_db development.ini
```

Comment: Use Alembic for database migrations: https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/. Example usage for the cookiecutter is described in the Pyramid SQL/URL Dispatch tutorial: https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/tutorials/wiki2/definingmodels.html#migrate-the-database-with-alembic

Comment: This is not a layered migration inserting data, this is when we are futzing with initial seed data only. I don't want to do this with a migration. I am following those steps to make the migration where the deb tables are created and then I run the command to seed the database which invokes setup_models.

Comment: I added my alembic invocation details to the issue

Comment: Are you using Alembic or not? If you don't want to use it, then you can delete the SQLite database file from the file system and rerun your db ini script.

Comment: Can you read my description in the question? I am using alembic to create the tables, see the `I am updating the db by running` section.

Comment: @spacether - So you don't want to DROP the tables you just want to DELETE all rows from them?

Comment: Delete all the rows from them and keep the table schemas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can do this by:

- looping over all model classes
- making all instances of those classes as to be deleted
- committing the session/transaction to delete them
- THEN seeding the data
  the below code does this:

```
import transaction
from ..models.meta import Base

def delete_table_rows(dbsession):
    model_clases = [cls for cls in Base.__subclasses__()]
    with transaction.manager as tx:
        for model_clases in model_clases:
            for instance in dbsession.query(model_clases).all():
                dbsession.delete(instance)
        transaction.commit()


def setup_models(dbsession):
    """
    Add or update models / fixtures in the database.

    """
    delete_table_rows(dbsession)
    # your custom seed code here
    model = models.mymodel.MyModel(name='one', value=1)
    dbsession.add(model)
```

Answer (score 1):

By default, SQLite does not enforce foreign key constraints at the engine level (even if you have declared them in the table DDL), so you could probably just use something as simple as

```py
insp = inspect(engine)
with engine.begin() as conn:
    for table_name in insp.get_table_names():
        conn.exec_driver_sql(f'DELETE FROM "{table_name}"')
```

Comment: Hi there, I asked for code that one can add to the above setup_models function.
Can you include the needed imports and include it in the setup_models function?